# Controlar formato y tipo de TextBox c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, textbox, keypressevent

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que necesito controlar que uno de mis campos TextBox solo contenga números y el otro contenga números y letras mayúsculas con el siguiente formato: `QQQ111`. Quiero que haga la comprobación al abandonar el campo, y no cada vez que se escriba en él.
Uso Visual Studio 2019.
Este es mi código:

```
private void SoloNumeros(KeyPressEventArgs v)
{
   // solo admite del 0-9
   if ((v.KeyChar >= 32 && v.KeyChar <= 47) || (v.KeyChar >= 58 && v.KeyChar <= 255))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Solo se admiten números", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
      v.Handled = true;
      return;
   }
}

private void tNumeroPropuesta_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   SoloNumeros(e);
}

private void LetrasMayusYNumeros(KeyPressEventArgs v)
{
   // solo admite de A-Z y 0-9
   if ((v.KeyChar >= 32 && v.KeyChar <= 47) || (v.KeyChar >= 58 && v.KeyChar <= 64) || (v.KeyChar >= 91 && v.KeyChar <= 255))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Solo se admiten letras mayúsculas y números siguiendo el siguiente formato: 'QQQ111'", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
      v.Handled = true;
      return;
   }
}


private void tNumeroPlaca_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   LetrasMayusYNumeros(e);
}
```

He visto que para que solo compruebe al final, tengo que usar lo siguiente, pero no sé cómo hacer que lea los caracteres:

```
private void tNumeroPropuesta_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: podes mirar el contenido del campo... no tenes porque usar los argumentos... es mas, en sender, tenes el objeto que levanto el evento

Comment: @gbianchi ¿y cómo podría controlar su formato y tipo?

Comment: una expresion regular, o caracter a caracter...

Comment: @gbianchi con ```String.Format```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes usar algo asi:

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Asignamos el evento al perder el foco del control
        textBox1.Leave += TextBox1_Leave;
        textBox2.Leave += TextBox2_Leave;
    }


    private void TextBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!EsLetrasMayusYNumeros(textBox2.Text.Trim()))
        {                
            MessageBox.Show("Solo se admiten letras mayúsculas y números siguiendo el siguiente formato: 'QQQ111'", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
    }



    private void TextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!EsNumero(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Solo se admiten números", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
     
       
    }


    //Metodo que valida la entrada de numeros y letras
    private bool EsLetrasMayusYNumeros(string texto)
    {
        // solo admite de A-Z y 0-9
        foreach (char letra in texto)//Recoremos el string para validar letra por letra
        {
            if ((letra >= 32 && letra <= 47) || (letra >= 58 && letra <= 64) 
                || (letra>= 91 && letra <= 255))
            {                   
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
       
    }



    private bool EsNumero(String cadena) 
    {         
        int numero = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(cadena, out numero))
        {
            return false;    
        }
        return true;

    }


 //Validando campo con expresiones regulares 
    private bool EsLetrasMayusYNumerosRegExp(string texto)
    {
        // solo admite de Q r veces y 0-9 3 digitos
        string validacion = @"^[Q]{3}[0-9]{3}$";
        return Regex.IsMatch(texto, validacion);
    }
```

he puesto el método de números a validarlo como un int a manera de ejemplo, este método fracasara si la cadena es muy larga, en ese caso puedes usar un ciclo for o tratarlo como double, también puedes usar expresiones regulares tanto para el campo números como el de números y letras, aunque creo que eso excede los alcances de tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora funciona como quería.

Comment: @luciacar la respuesta esta bien.. pero ojo, porque tambien admite el valor 123QQQ que segun vos no era valido..

Comment: @gbianchi es verdad, me acabo de dar cuenta. Pero lo demás funciona bien.

Comment: Claro.. pero a menos que arregle eso, esta respuesta esta bien, pero no esta correcta.... @luciacar

Comment: bueno si pones las reglas de validación podría ayudarte mas por ejemplo que letras quieres, o que cantidad de números son en el campo solonumeros

Comment: Eh agregado un método alternativo para validar con expresiones regulares

Comment: @EmmanuelGarciaValdez con eso ultimo esta genial!

Answer (score 0):

La ccomprobacion de que cosa se ingresa, lo optimo es hacerlo en el keypress, solo que en tu caso, para comodidad, debes quitarle el msgbox para que no incomode al usuario cada vez que se equivoca, simplemente la accion debe ser ser dejar o no dejar ingresar lo que corresponde.
Tambien se puede hacer al dejar el textbox (evento Leave), pero al final tendrias una cadena y tendrias que recorrerla caracter por caracter y eso se ve innecesario. Los leave son mas para tratar el dato ya como cadena, valor completo y dar formato ("0,00"), redondear, cortar la cadena, calcular y hacer operaciones con el dato, etc.
Te dejo una mejor opcion:

```
private void txtnombre_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == '-')
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Como ves eso es para un campo de nombre, se puede ingresar letras, numeros el punto, la coma, el guion, dar tab, enter, shift, espacio. Ya vas eliminando en el IF las condiciones que no necesites.

Este otro a continuacion es para validar campos de montos, valida que solo se ingresen numero y un solo punto en caso se va a ingresar un decimal:

```
private void txtstockmin_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "." && !txtstockmin.Text.ToString().Contains(".")))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Para validar que solo ingresen mayusculas, lo mejor es no validar, simplemente convertir lo que se ingrese en mayuscula:

```
private void txtnombre_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtnombre.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
    }
```

Para terminar, aqui un ejemplo de para que sirve mas el evento Leave (y no es para lo que solicitabas inicialmente)

```
private void txtpreciocompra_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtpreciocompra.Text.ToString() != "")
        {
            txtpreciocompra.Text = txtpreciocompra.Text.Trim('.');
            txtpreciocompra.Text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(txtpreciocompra.Text), 2).ToString("0.00");
        }
    }
```

Saludos.